# Upgrade from 12.04 to 14.04 installed Samba4! Shares not accessible

Tags: upgrade, samba

So today I upgraded my ubuntu server version to the latest and in the process it asked me to keep the samba config file or upgrade it. I said to keep it as always.

When it finished the upgrade I noticed that my shares weren't accessible, ie, asking for password.
When checked the samba version it says: Samba version 4.1.6-Ubuntu.

The smb.conf file is still the same but I can only access the shares with the administrator password. All other users from the network cannot access the shares. Note that I have AD managing the users/groups.

If I set guestok = yes all the users can access the share but this is not what I wanted.

So, first, why did samba upgraded to 4?
How do I make the domain users access the shares as before?
I'm thinking of downgrading samba4 to samba3 but how do I do that?

here's my smb.conf file:

[global]

```
    idmap backend = tdb
    idmap gid = 10000-20000
    idmap uid = 10000-20000
    idmap config NPDOMLX : backend = rid
    idmap config NPDOMLX : range = 10000 - 20000
    obey pam restrictions = yes
    dns proxy = no
    netbios name = NPLX02
    guest ok = yes
    load printers = yes
    printing = cups
    printcap name = cups

    workgroup = NPDOMLX
    security = ADS
    winbind separator = +
    max log size = 1000
    log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
    socket options = TCP_NODELAY
    wins server = 192.168.0.5
    map to guest = bad user
    domain master = no
    encrypt passwords = no
    winbind use default domain = yes
    realm = NPDOMLX.LOCAL
    passdb backend = tdbsam
    template shell = /bin/bash
    server string = Storage Server
    password server = npdc01.npdomlx.local
    winbind enum users = yes
    path = /var/spool/samba
    winbind nested groups = yes
    unix password sync = yes
    template homedir = /home/%D/%U
    winbind enum groups = yes
    syslog = 0
    panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
    pam password change = yes
```

Comment: Try with restarting the samba, it might helps. Please use the command "sudo service smbd restart".

Comment: did not work.
this configuration file was working while on samba3. In samba4 it is not..